# Does JW player support HTTP2?

Tags: jwplayer, http2

I am currently working on a project where we are using JW Player 7.11.1, we are planning to support http2 for our website, could you please help me understand, Does JW player support HTTP2?

Answer (score 1):

You will not have problems, HTTP2 maintains high-level compatibility with HTTP 1.1.

doc: https://http2.github.io/faq/

> we can work on new mechanisms that are version-independent, as long as
>   they’re backwards-compatible with the existing Web

I'm using JwPLyer 7.x with HTTP2 without problems.

Comment: Thanks @Francesco for your valuable inputs :)